# XCODE Error :- dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libLTO.dylib, executable works on terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I see similar question been asked and there are a few answers, but none of those apply to what I'm looking for, so here I go :-

I am using XCODE 8.3 and I downloaded llvm and followed all the steps in here :-

http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

I created an XCODE Command Line C++ Tool in which I tried to include CLANG headers, like `clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h` etc.

It threw a bunch of errors (linking errors) so I linked against all the generated LLVM and CLANG .a and .dylib files.

All the errors were gone except these  :-

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libLTO.dylib
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclang.dylib
```

No matter what I did, inspite of these libraries being in the same folder as other .a files, XCODE Never picked these two items for some reason.

I used `install_tool` to correct the path in the executable and everything was fine, I was able to print `hello world` faithfully.

Now, here is the problem :-

Even though executable works on Terminal, In XCODE I've been STILL battling to get past the error w.r.t. libLTO.dylib above. It throws the exact same error in LLVM debug window and hence I can't use the XCODE debugger.

1.) If the executable works on Terminal why not on XCODE ? I'm not rebuilding the binary everytime, so we can rule out those errors. Whatever `install_tool`  did after the build is clearly not understood by XCODE. How can I correct that ?

Here is the otool output :-
`otool -L <<executable>>` 
I do see some difference in compatibility. Not sure if that's an issue.

```
@rpath/libLTO.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
@rpath/libclang.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
```

Is there a simpler way to get started on clang parser in XCODE instead of downloading everything and building from scratch ? 
Thanks so much for reading through, help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround :-

Download prebuild binaries (as opposed to source code) from

```
http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html
```

And then, in the list of available libs, DO NOT ADD `clang.dylib`. Instead add all the other clang*.a files. My guess is, they are the ones compling into `clang.dylib` so it should be OK.

Do `llvm-config --system-libs` and add the other libs.
Everything should work (at least for me it did).